# GestureDetector fling wrong direction

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have an implementation of a `BottomDrawer` which implements `GestureDetector` to determine when the user flings the bottom drawer. I am having two issues with this:

1) The `onFling` does not always get called. This is a relatively minor problem.

2) The velocity passed to the `onFling` is frequently of the wrong direction. This is a huge problem as it leads to the user flinging the drawer to close, and it opening, or vice versa. Is this an issue anyone has come across before? How can this be resolved? I thought perhaps of ignoring flings less than a certain magnitude, but the erroneous velocities can sometimes be of a pretty large magnitude, so that doesn't help.

Here is the code of my `BottomDrawer` class, I can also upload a demo project to GitHub if that would be helpful:

```
package com.cbendeb.bottomdrawer.view;

import android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A bottom extensible drawer. Displays two views, one as the handle and one as the content.
 * 
 * @author catherine
 */
public final class BottomDrawer extends LinearLayout implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private static final String TAG = BottomDrawer.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int ANIMATE_DURATION = 500;

    private float lastTouchY;

    // so we don't have to recalculate this stuff all the time
    private float openY;
    private float closedY;
    private float currentY = -1;

    // listeners for the end of the open and close animations
    private AnimatorListener closeListener;
    private AnimatorListener openListener;

    // gestures
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private boolean flung = false;

    public BottomDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public BottomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public BottomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the drawer is expanded
     */
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return currentY != closedY;
    }

    /**
     * Opens the drawer.
     */
    public void open() {

        animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setDuration(
                        Math.max(0, (int) (ANIMATE_DURATION * (getY() - openY) / (closedY - openY))))
                .setListener(openListener).start();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the drawer.
     */
    public void close() {

        animate()
                .translationY(getChildAt(1).getHeight())
                .setDuration(
                        Math.max(0,
                                (int) (ANIMATE_DURATION * (closedY - getY()) / (closedY - openY))))
                .setListener(closeListener).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getActionMasked();
        final float y = ev.getRawY();

        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Calculate the distance moved
                final float dy = y - lastTouchY;

                if (getY() + dy < closedY && getY() + dy > openY) {
                    setY(getY() + dy);

                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                flung = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d(TAG, "flung: " + flung);
                if (!flung) {
                    if (getY() >= (openY + closedY) / 2) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "closing");
                        close();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "opening");
                        open();
                    }
                }

                flung = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
        }
        lastTouchY = y;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        openY = getBottom() - getChildAt(0).getHeight() - getChildAt(1).getHeight();
        closedY = getBottom() - getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        if (currentY == -1) {
            currentY = closedY;
        }
        if (changed && isOpen()) {
            setY(openY);
        } else if (changed && !isOpen()) {
            setY(closedY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFling velocityY: " + velocityY + " currentY " + currentY);
        final float y = getY();
        if (velocityY < 0 && y > openY && y < closedY) { // moving upwards
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling opening");
            open();
        } else if (velocityY > 0 && y > openY && y < closedY) { // moving downwards
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling closing");
            close();
        }
        flung = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // Do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // Do nothing
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm looking into the GestureDetector implementation on GrepCode... but it would be nice if there was an easier way to resolve this.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? facing the same problem where onFling returns the wrong direction sign

Comment: Yeah, my solution was implementing my own gesture detection. :-/ At least for velocity fling.

Comment: @Catherine could you please answer this question with the code you used for your fling detector?

Comment: @Catherine can you post your solution please?